# How to get Django Queryset to filter one model entries depending on another model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-template-filters

I'm trying to filter the entries from one Model (Product) depending on what the user has bought (EntryProduct).

I've been looking to other posts but none of them could solve my problem.

I'm using Django 2.0.

First of all I'm going to explain how this store works:
One product is formed by a certain group of content. What the user have to buy is the content of this products, not the product itself (as most of the stores), so for that, the process of buying that I did is: In `EntryProduct`, I added a boolean for each content that the products have, so everytime the user buys content from a product, there is a function that creates a new entry putting the related boolean to true. So I have 1 entry for each content buyed by user and product.

All the buying system is already done, but the problem for me now is when I have to create the view of the products buyed (show all buyed content for each product with at least one content buyed). What I had in mind is:

- First get the 'Entries' filtering by the logged user.
- Then group by product (so I could have all the content buyed by that user).
- And create the queryset passing just the content buyed of the products to the Template, so there I can print them.

This is just what I thinked, but I don't know how to create that Queryset and then print the content to the template...

The other way that I thinked is to pass a queryset of products, and another of entries and filter in the own template. Example:(just the if excluding the `for`s)

```
{% if entry.user=user and entry.abstract %}
    {{prod.abstract}}
{% endif %}
```

But I don't think this way is the best to do this... I'm quite new to Django and I'm not really sure which is the best practice for this case.

(related) **Models**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(_('Product Name'), max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    it_exist = models.BooleanField(_('is an existing idea?'), default=False)
    # content
    content_tweet = models.CharField(_('Content Tweet'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    content_abstract = models.CharField(_('Content Abstract'), max_length=3000, blank=True)
    canvas_01 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/canvas_01/', blank=True)
    executive_resume = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/executive_resume', blank=True)
    graphic_01 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/graphic_01', blank=True)
    business_plan = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/business_plan', blank=True)
    investor_deck = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/investor_deck', blank=True)
    graphic_02 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/graphic_02', blank=True)
    # prices
    price_tweet = models.IntegerField(_('Tweet Price in Tokens'), default=0)
    price_abstract = models.IntegerField(_('Abstract Price in Tokens'), default=50)
    price_canvas_01 = models.IntegerField(_('Canvas 01 Price in Tokens'), default=500)
    price_executive_resume = models.IntegerField(_('Executive Resume Price in Tokens'), default=1000)
    price_graphic_01 = models.IntegerField(_('Graphic 01 Price in Tokens'), default=1000)
    price_business_plan = models.IntegerField(_('Business Plan Price in Tokens'), default=10000)
    price_investor_deck = models.IntegerField(_('Investor Deck Price in Tokens'), default=7500)
    price_graphic_02 = models.IntegerField(_('Graphic 02 Price in Tokens'), default=5000)
    # extra
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(
        _('deleted'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this product should be treated as deleted. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting products.'
        ),
    )
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'owner')

    def get_categories(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.category.all()])

    def get_tags(self):
        return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.tag.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # Here's where to take a look
    def soft_delete(self):
        self.is_deleted = True
        self.deleted_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()

class EntryProduct(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(_('Content Tweet'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(_('Price in Tokens'), default=0)
    tweet = models.BooleanField(_('tweet is buyed'), default=False)
    abstract = models.BooleanField(_('abstract is buyed'), default=False)
    canvas_01 = models.BooleanField(_('canvas 01 is buyed'), default=False)
    executive_resume = models.BooleanField(_('executive resume is buyed'), default=False)
    graphic_01 = models.BooleanField(_('graphic 01 is buyed'), default=False)
    business_plan = models.BooleanField(_('business plan is buyed'), default=False)
    investor_deck = models.BooleanField(_('investor deck is buyed'), default=False)
    graphic_02 = models.BooleanField(_('graphic 02 is buyed'), default=False)
    buy_date = models.DateTimeField(_('buy date'), default=timezone.now)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

(related) **View**:

```
# view for the buyer-product-list page
class BuyerProductListView(generic.ListView):
    # name of the object to be used in the store/buyer_product_list.html
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'store/buyer_product_list.html'
    paginate_by = 3

    # TODO get the right queries.
    # HERE IS WHERE I THINK I HAVE TO DO THE WORK
    # THIS QUERYSET IS WRONG FOR THIS PURPOUSE.
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(BuyerProductListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(is_deleted=False, owner=self.request.user).order_by('-id')
        return queryset

    # Make the view only available for the users with current fields
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_buyer:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Extra question**: Do you think that it would be a good idea to add the following `meta` to the `EntryProduct` to evade repeated entries?

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = (('user', 'product', 'tweet'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'abstract'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'canvas_01'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'executive_resume'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'graphic_01'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'business_plan'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'investor_deck'),
                        ('user', 'product', 'graphic_02'))
```

I hope I've explained myself clear. Thank you in advance.

Also if you think there is any way of improving my code or make the buy method more efficient please, suggestions welcome :)

Comment: If you write several `unique_together`s like that, only the last one will still exist, due to Pythons evaluation.

Comment: But in short: you want all `Product`s for which there exists a `ProductEntity` for that user?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, all `product`s for which there exists a `ProductEntry` for that user, but also filter the content of each `product` with the booleans related in `ProductEntry`.

Comment: So it means that `canvas1` of the `product` should be equal to `canvas1` of the corresponding `productentry`, and so on right?

Comment: Personally I find it a bit chaotic design. I would use three classes: `Product`, `SpecProduct` and `SpecProductOrder`, where the `SpecProduct` has such booleans, and the `SpecProductOrder` refers to such spec'ed product, since if you then add an extra boolean, you do not need to change the filter.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you are saying, but to be sure, could you please give me an example?
The design I did give me the possibility to make a ProductEntry with multiple content (cnavas_01 and abstract, for example). Do your design work as well for that?

Comment: but can you first confirm that the `ProductEntry` should have *all* boolean fealds equal to that of the `Product` when we filter?

Comment: yes, It should have the same number of booleans as contents in product. @WillemVanOnsem